# What issues would lead to a deployed Matlab application not to write to an excel file?

Tags: matlab, matlab-deployment, matlab-compiler

My code works perfectly.

When I deployed the gui code the data no longer exports to excel. I'm using xlswrite to populate excel by row.

What complications could cause a deployed application to export to excel differently than matlab code?

Comment: Run the exe from a dos prompt to see any errors thrown. It's probably trying to write to the folder where the exe is and it doesn't have permission would be my guess

Comment: I followed your advice but no errors were thrown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It had to do with the path and file name.

In matlab the excel file was in the current folder and had no problem finding it.

In the deployed app, it had trouble finding the excel file with only the file name to go off of.

Solution: I used the whole pathname/filename